# CSV File - Pandas/Python, print function

Tags: python, pandas

I've been going through a CSV data file using the code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("TB_burden_countries_2018-03-06.csv")
df2 = df.loc[df["country"]=="Afghanistan","cfr"]
print(df2)
df3 = df.loc[df["country"]=="Afghanistan","e_pop_num"]
print(df3)
df4 = df.loc[df["country"]=="Afghanistan","e_inc_num"]
print(df4)
```

What I've noticed with the output, as an example is this:

```
Name: e_pop_num, dtype: int64
0     38000
1     40000
2     42000
3     44000
4     46000
5     47000
6     49000
7     50000
8     52000
9     53000
10    55000
11    56000
12    58000
13    60000
14    62000
15    64000
16    65000
```

I was wondering how I could remove the numbers on the LHS, from 0 to 16? They correlate to the country Afghanistan from the CSV file, but it's annoying when I'm looking at different areas and the 0-16 numbers pop up, as I manually remove them for further data work.

What could I do?

Comment: Why not set the index first `df = df.set_index(['country'])` then query i.e `df.loc["Afghanistan","e_inc_num"]` ??

Comment: Hey Dark, cheers for that. The removal of the numbers and now its showing the countries is helpful, but if I was able the countries entirely and show the numbers, that would be great.

Comment: James I'm not getting what you are trying to convey.!

Comment: `country
Afghanistan    38000Afghanistan    40000Afghanistan    42000Afghanistan    44000Afghanistan    46000Afghanistan    47000Afghanistan    49000Afghanistan    50000Afghanistan    52000
Afghanistan    53000Afghanistan    55000
Afghanistan    56000Afghanistan    58000Afghanistan    60000Afghanistan    62000Afghanistan    64000
Afghanistan    65000`
But I was hoping to change it so the output is only
`country
    38000    40000    42000    44000    46000    47000    49000
    50000    52000    53000    55000    56000    58000    60000    62000    64000    65000`

Comment: I ran out of characters before, but basically I'm trying to keep the specific columns and rows, but for output I wouldn't mind trying to remove the countrie and just have the numbers only. Also, sorry for explaining myself poorly!

Comment: James if you dont want the index just print the values i.e `df.loc["Afghanistan","e_inc_num"].values`, if you tell me the purpose of why you need that kind of print i can help you better

Comment: Hey Dark, that works perfectly. Honestly, I'm new at using Python/Pandas so I'm just practicing doing basic data extraction and making basic graphs from CSV files. So, nothing too complicated yet. But thank you so much for your help, exactly what I was looking for